# Correctly installing wordpress LAMP - Changing site path for WordPress on ubuntu lamp server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, ubuntu

Trying to install WordPress on ubuntu. I followed this `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WordPress` article in order to get my WordPress install running which was successful. Unfortunately, I have WordPress installed in the wrong place or I am not linking the site correctly. My issue is I installed it at `wordpress.dev` on my local machine, the domain it made me install it was on `wordpress.dev/wordpress/` however I would like this link to be `wordpress.dev` as the root.

If i change the settings in `http://wordpress.dev/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php` of the `site-url` to be `http://wordpress.dev` instead of `http://wordpress.dev/wordpress/` it does not work and apache2 shows me the folder WordPress when I go to `wordpress.dev`.

How can I fix this as I am not sure if I need to add anything in the `sites-enabled` apache2 folder or something in my `known_hosts` or `.htaccess`?

Thanks for helping if you can. :)

Comment: Thanks @Dhruvin for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out that actually installing via ubuntu `apt-get` was not the best option. I assume you have a LAMP stack installed. I followed these steps:

- Download wordpress
- Create a folder in /var/www/wordpress
- extract the wordpress
- put the contents of the folder into your /var/www/wordpress folder
- boot up your LAMP server ie. `service apache2 start`
- login to your phpmyadmin and create  a database for your Wordpress install ie. wordpress or wp
- set up a new user on the priveledges tab whilst granting priveledges to this database
- go back to your /var/www/wordpress folder and rename wp-config-sample.php to wp-config.php
- open the file and fill in all the necessary field and save
- now go to your /etc/apache2/sites-available folder
- create a new file called wordpress.conf or can be whatever you like mine was wordpress.dev.conf
- if you dont know what should be in this file copy the default one or open that up and just change the directives that point it to the wordpress install so /var/www/wordpress or wherever you placed it and give it a site url so mine was wordpress.dev for example and save
- open up your /etc/hosts with root priveledges and add your site so 127.0.0.1 followed by a tab space and then the name you want url to be which should match your wordpress.conf we created earlier in terms of site url and save.
- run in your CL `sudo a2ensite wordpress.dev` wordpress.dev being the name of the conf file without the `.conf` at the end in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`
- it should automatically tell you to run `sudo apache2 reload` in the CL but if it doesn't run it.
- if successful, go to the url you site and voila... proceed with your installation.

Although the order can be changed slightly this is a rough guideline.